# Return random elements nested in mongo document

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I has the following json document in Mongo db. The show element will have several season elements which will also have several episodes elements that in turn have multiple questionEntry elements.

```
 {
"show":[
{
 "season":[
    {
       "episodes":[
          {
             "questionEntry":{
                "id":1,
                "info":{
                   "seasonNumber":1,
                   "episodeNumber":5,
                   "episodeName":"A Hero Sits Next Door"
                },
                "questionItem":{
                   "theQuestion":"What is the name of the ringer hired by Mr. Weed?",
                   "attachedElement":{
                      "type":1,
                      "value":""
                   }
                },
                "options":[
                   {
                      "type":1,
                      "value":"Johnson"
                   },
                   {
                      "type":1,
                      "value":"Hideo"
                   },
                   {
                      "type":1,
                      "value":"Guillermo"
                   }
                ],
                "answer":{
                   "questionId":1,
                   "answer":3
                },
                "metaTags":[
                   "Season 1",
                   "Episode 5",
                   "Trivia",
                   "Arya Stark",
                   "House Stark"
                ]
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
}
]
}
```

I have been able to return questionElement(s) where the questionElements metaTag entry equals my search. E.G. if a metaTag element equals my string then return the questionEntry element that the metaTag element resides in and search the whole show element and return all that match using this code:
(thanks to Yathish Manjunath for help with this piece of code)

```
 private DB mongoDatabase;
 private DBCollection mongoColl;
 private DBObject dbObject;

 // Singleton class
 // Create client (server address(host,port), credential, options)
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), 
            Collections.singletonList(credential),
            options);

 mongoDatabase = ClientSingleton.getInstance().getClient().getDB("MyDB");
 queryMetaTags("Season 1");

     //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void queryMetaTags(String query)
{            
    List<String> continentList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{query});
    DBObject matchFields = new 
       BasicDBObject("show.season.questions.questionEntry.metaTags", 
      new BasicDBObject("$in", continentList));
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id",
       "$_id").append("questions", 
       new BasicDBObject("$push","$show.season.questions"));
    //System.out.println("2");
    DBObject unwindshow = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$show");
    DBObject unwindsea = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$show.season");
    DBObject unwindepi = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", 
      "$show.season.questions");
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", matchFields);
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);  
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    AggregationOutput output = 
    mongoColl.aggregate(unwindshow,unwindsea,unwindepi,match,group);
    String s = JSON.serialize(dbObject);
    JSONObject json = null;

    for (DBObject result : output.results()) 
    {
        System.out.println(result);
        // pretty view for testing
        try 
        {
             json = new JSONObject(result);
             System.out.println(json.toString(4));
        } 
        catch (JSONException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("In end of queryMetaTags");
}
```

I want to search like above but only return 10 random matching questionEntry elements? What is the best and most efficient way to achieve this?

I have to say I'm totally new to search queries for any database and just can't figure out how to achieve a slick solution? Hopefully somebody here can help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) in the aggregation chain. Note that you have to add it as the last chain.

`{ $limit: <positive integer> }`

So in your case,

`{ $limit: 10 }`

Comment: is this a random collection from the document, if so in which line should I add the limit statement? I need to retrieve 10 random elements that match my search criteria!

Comment: The limit should be added as the last item in the aggregate chain. What exactly do you mean by random collection from the document? The limit will retrieve the first 10 matching documents that come out of your aggregate

Comment: Apologies I shall make myself clear. The above code returns any questionEntry elements that have a metaTag element which matches my search string and it searches the enitre show document. Great, but I want to extract from that a random 10 questionEntry elements from the total number that is returned. At the moment it returns all matching questionEntry elements. I'm not good with queries at all and can't figure out what is the best/efficient way  to accomplish this? If possible I would also like to insert each of the random 10 questionEntry that returned into a list too?

Comment: AFAIK there is no random element in mongodb query. However, you can use the [$skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) by which you can skip certain elements. So you can generate a random number and use it in the skip value. So `{ $skip: 10}, {$limit: 10}` would give you dcouments from 11 to 20. `{ $skip: 15}, {$limit: 10}` - would give documents 16-25

Comment: OK thanks - looks like I will have to somehow put the returned questionEntry elements from the query into something that I can iterate across and Use Java's Random methos to pull out a selection of 10!?

Comment: You can do that from Java itself, or pass it through the skip function. Both have advantages and disadvantages: Java random - you have to get all the documents from mongodb into your application, then you can choose random 10. Doing it from MongoDB itself - you only get at the max 10, but you need to know how much you can skip... lets say if you have only total of 15 documents for that query, then you cannot skip 15 itself..

Comment: How would I get the docu,ents into Java so I can use random to select 10?